# Encrypt, secure a .ini file for INFOMAKER

Tags: config, ini, infomaker

I would like to secure or at least hide my server credentials from the .ini file generated when creating an executable file from INFOMAKER. I do not think that I can do anything about the coding of the executables generated from the Infomaker.

I am not just comfortable with the credentials lying around in plain text.

Already tried different connection methods including SQL directly, and ODBC connections.

If there is a way that I can hide or get rid of the ini file entirely, that would be great.